# Getting rid of extra string in result after loop through list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So I am trying to do a function that takes strings from a list, and basically what I want at the end is a string with list[0]+'OR'+....+list[sizeofList], for example result = DATA1 OR DATA2 OR DATA3. My code currently returns that except it does put an OR after the last string, which I do not want. I tried putting an if condition if j ==sizeofList, then result = list[j] only but it's not working. Thank you in advance,

```
def format_list():
    j = 0
    list = data_file['data']
    sizeofList = len(list)

    for j in range(0, sizeofList):
       result = list[j] + ' ' + 'OR'
       j=j+1
       result = print(result)

    return result
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`

Comment: also, `' OR '.join(data_file['data'])`

Comment: thank you works like a charm !!

Answer (score 1):

Just like the comment from @acushner suggests, join is perfect for this use case.

```
mylist = ["test1", "test2", "Test3"]
result = " OR ".join(mylist)
print(result)
```

If you would like a solution similar to what you had originally, I would approach this by looping through all items except for the last one. Then appending the last item without an `" OR "`.

```
def format_list(mylist):
    result = ""
    # Add each word except the last word
    for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1):
        result += mylist[i] + " OR "
    # Add the last word from the list to the string, without an OR
    result += mylist[-1]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_list():
    j = 0
    list = data_file['data']
    sizeofList = len(list)

    for j in range(0, sizeofList-1):
       result = list[j] + ' ' + 'OR'
       # j=j+1 >> No need for that since you're in a for loop
       print(result) # No need for "result = " since you just print

    result = list[sizeofList]
    result = print(result)

    return result
```

I didn't test it but it might work

You do the same thing as you did before, but separate the last iteration, since it's the one causing problems in your case (because you have the last "OR")